# Upward Voltage Level Translation

Tags: level-shifting, level-translation

I need to up-translate two complementary 2.5 V signals to 5 V. I am looking for a circuit which can do this and which consumes ultra-low static power. I tried to design one, using 4 MOSFETs as shown below:
[image]

The circuit uses 4 MOSFETs in a cross coupled configuration to generate the desired signals. However, I was unable to reduce the shoot through current in the MOSFETs beyond a point (Large values of R1 and R2 affects my output rise time) and the circuit is still consuming close to 50 uW at 5V VDD. I am using the output of this circuit to drive other MOSFETs which have a combined capacitance of 1nF. I want the total power consumption of this driver to be less than 10 uW. So, I searched for level shifting ICs on Digikey's and Mouser's websites, but unfortunately couldn't find a part matching my requirement. I found a part from NXP on their [website](http://cache.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74AXP1T34.pdf), however they haven't started shipping it yet. I am hoping if somebody could suggest me a better circuit or provide an alternative to the IC I am looking for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look here: https://www.google.nl/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwilwq2k7vvLAhUFDA8KHbaNBE4QjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.analog.com%2Funiversity%2Fcourses%2Felectronics%2Felectronics-lab-voltage-level-shifter&psig=AFQjCNFf9FAj7_SgkTp5kxAhlDKWXFRgnw&ust=1460095585905237  Figure 2 shows a **proper** levelshifter that consumes **zero** power when static.

Comment: Also TI has plenty of **voltage level translators** see: http://www.ti.com/logic/docs/translationresults.tsp?sectionId=458&voltageIn=2.5&searchDirection=1&voltageOut=5.0#voltintf  Also see this selection guide: http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/scyb018h/scyb018h.pdf

Comment: @FakeMoustache I am using the same configuration of the level shifter which is shown in Fig. 2 & Fig. 4 of the Analog Devices link you sent me.

Comment: And still you're not getting (almost) zero static power consumption while the circuit from my link does meet that requirement (I know, because I designed many of them). Can you guess why ? Hint: the circuit is mainly used on-chip.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Under static conditions, the circuit I built consumes negligible current. I was talking about the shoot-through current during operation of the circuit, which adds to the switching losses and increases the total dynamic power consumption.

Comment: That's also related to the transistors. You're using switching transistors which have a huge Cgs (compared to the ones used on a chip). Also you should have much weaker PMOS than NMOS, something you cannot do so easily off-chip. To do this function efficiently you have to use an IC to do the job.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Thank your for the comments. I will try to see if I can achieve a better power consumption using any of the ICs from Ti in the list you provided.